# Parsing JSON from POST request using Python and FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I'm trying to parse a JSON that came from a POST request from user to my API made with FastAPI. I have a nested JSON that can receive multiple values and my problem is: How can I parse it and get the values from this nested JSON?

The JSON is like this:

```
{
    "recipe": [
    {
        "ingredient": "rice",
        "quantity": 1.5
        },
    {
        "ingredient": "carrot",
        "quantity": 1.8
        },
    {
        "ingredient": "beans",
        "quantity": 1.8
        }
    ]
}
```

I must grab the all values from the list *recipe* separated, as I have a database with this *ingredient* and will query all of this and do some calculates with the quantity given from user. But I don't even know how I can parse this JSON from the POST request.

I already have a 2 classes with Pydantic validating this values like:

```
class Ingredientes(BaseModel):
    ingredient: str
    quantity: float


class Receita(BaseModel):
    receita: List[Ingredientes] = []
```

Edit 1: I tried to include it in my function that recieve this POST request and didn't work like:

```
@app.post('/calcul', status_code=200)
def calculate_table(receita: Receita):
    receipe = receita["receita"]
    for ingredient in receipe:
        return f'{ingredient["ingredient"]}: {ingredient["quantity"]}'
```

Edit 2: Fixed the issue with the code bellow(Thanks MatsLindh):

```
@app.post('/calcul', status_code=200)
def calculate_table(receita: Receita):
    receipe = receita.receita
    for ingredient in receipe:
        return f'{ingredient.ingrediente}: {ingredient.quantidade}'
```

Comment: You can then access `receita.receita` to get all ingredients (not receita['receita']). If this doesn't work, add the error message you get to your question.

Comment: I got a type error for now, feeling closer: TypeError: 'Ingredientes' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Yeah, that's because you're attempting to access it as a key `['foo']` and not as a property `.foo`. Use `ingredient.ingredient` and `ingredient.quantity`.

Comment: Got it! I could get it now, but looks very strange because when I send a post request it just return to me the first item of the list.

Comment: Also, when I swap the return in the loop for print I can get all items in the list printed in my terminal, but when using the return I just can get the first item of the list in the postman.

Comment: If you're returning _inside the for_, the return will be called when you first iterate over anything - i.e. the first element will be returned. If you want to return a list of strings for each ingredient + quantity, you can create a list and return that (but usually it'd be better to just return the existing ingredient list as JSON instead).

Comment: Awesome! That's great for what I need. Thank you very much for that, really appreciate!

Answer (score -1):

To parse a JSON-formatted string (from the POST request, for example) into a dictionary, use the `loads` function from the `json` module, like this:

```py
import json

s = """{
    "recipe": [
    {
        "ingredient": "rice",
        "quantity": 1.5
        },
    {
        "ingredient": "carrot",
        "quantity": 1.8
        },
    {
        "ingredient": "beans",
        "quantity": 1.8
        }
    ]
}
"""
recipe = json.loads(s)["recipe"]
for ingredient in recipe:
    print(f"{ingredient['ingredient']}: {ingredient['quantity']}")
```